# How is this equation evaluated $\binom {n}2 = \frac{n^2}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, factorial

I would like to know how $\binom {n}2 = \dfrac{n^2}{2}$ works out while I'm reading a proof on this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591958/communication-complexity-example-problem).

I have tried several ways, but I couldn't. i.e.

1. we knew that combinatorics formula that says, $\binom {n}2 = \dfrac{n!}{2! (n - 2)!} = ?$ the problem is that I don't how to get off from the binomial coefficient.
2. I went to **Stirling's formula** which says approximately, $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}{(\dfrac{n}{e})}^n = {(2\pi n)}^\dfrac{1}{2}{(\dfrac{n}{e})}^n$ since $n^n > e^n$, therefore $\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}$ goes bigger as n approaches to infinity. I don't know also how to simplify this into more small parts ..

Rosen in his book "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications" [[Rosen07, P.151]](http://www2.fiit.stuba.sk/~kvasnicka/Mathematics%20for%20Informatics/Rosen_Discrete_Mathematics_and_Its_Applications_7th_Edition.pdf) says that "factorial function grows extremely rapidly as n grows"; So, I try to connivance myself from this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591958/communication-complexity-example-problem) that $\binom {n}2 = \dfrac{n^2}{2}$ but I couldn't get it. Also, I know why this is true since the factorial function grows very quickly as n grows, so it is obviously not polynomial, instead it is exponential algorithm as it seems. So, why the lower bound is $O(n^2)$ "polynomial" and not "exponential"?

Thank you.

Comment: $n! = n (n-1) (n-2)!$, so it should be $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \approx \frac{n^2}{2}$ for big $n$.

Comment: @Chester Thank you so much, It takes 2 hours from me and I didn't get and only 1 minute to check your response and verify the answer. Thank you again ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equal; ${n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. But the difference between them is $n/2$, which is small enough that it can be rolled into the correction term in your link.